# replace any words in string that match an entry in list with a single tag (python)

Tags: python, nltk

I have a list of sentences (~100k sentences total) and a list of "infrequent words" (length ~20k).  I would like to run through each sentence and replace any word that matches an entry in "infrequent_words" with the tag "UNK".

(so as a small example, if

```
infrequent_words = ['dog','cat']
sentence = 'My dog likes to chase after cars'
```

Then after applying the transformation it should be

```
sentence = 'My unk likes for chase after cars'
```

I am having trouble finding an efficient way to do this.  This function below (applied to each sentence) works, but it is very slow and I know there must be something better.  Any suggestions?

```
def replace_infrequent_words(text,infrequent_words):
    for word in infrequent_words:
        text = text.replace(word,'unk')
    return text
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can take a look at https://pypi.org/project/flashtext/  it's supposed to be optimized for these kind of replacements

Answer (score 0):

```
infrequent_words = {'dog','cat'}
sentence = 'My dog likes to chase after cars'

def replace_infrequent_words(text, infrequent_words):
    words = text.split()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] in infrequent_words:
            words[i] = 'unk'
    return ' '.join(words)

print(replace_infrequent_words(sentence, infrequent_words))
```

Two things that should improve performance:

1. Use a `set` instead of a `list` for storing `infrequent_words`.
2. Use a `list` to store each word in `text` so you don't have to scan the entire text string with each replacement.

This doesn't account for grammar and punctuation but this should be a performance improvement from what you posted.